# django-celery without an amqp server (rabbitmq)

Tags: django, celery, amqp, task-queue

I am using celery for distributed task processing. I wanted to deploy my work on a web-host, just to show the working of my project.
So how can i get djcelery to use a database (sqlalchemy) as backend with django instead of rabbitmq or other amqp servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the Celery docs on ["Using Celery with Redis/Database as the messaging queue"](http://ask.github.com/celery/tutorials/otherqueues.html).

Essentially you need to install [ghettoq](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ghettoq), add it to your installed apps, add a setting `CARROT_BACKEND = "ghettoq.taproot.Database"` and run syncdb. Then magic happens.

Comment: Glad I could help. Another option which we've used for development is `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` which just executes the tasks locally without ever sending to the queue. If you just want to run on your dev machine or do a quick demo without setting up the queue this is cheap and dirty way to get it done.

Comment: hi Mark,  after these settings,  a celeryd or celerybeat service need to be running at background as well?

Comment: If you are using ghettoq then yes you need celeryd running. You only need celerybeat if you have periodic tasks. If you are running `CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` you do not need celeryd running since everything will run inline.

Comment: thanks mark, when i run 'python manage.py celeryd -l INFO' at my django project derectory, it seems fine. but  when i started the init script http://github.com/ask/celery/raw/master/contrib/debian/init.d/celeryd

as celeryd start i got this error 'celery.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Celery needs to be configured to run celeryd'

I have configured these

    # Where the Django project is.
    CELERYD_CHDIR="/opt/Project/"
    
    # Path to celeryd
    CELERYD="/opt/Project/manage.py celeryd"
    
    # Name of the projects settings module.
    export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="settings"

Comment: My guess would be that it's a problem with how you have defined the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and what directories are on your `sys.path` but I don't think the comments are the best place for this. I would open up a new question with your `/etc/default/celeryd` file and the stacktrace of the error.